# How to see the link of the website it redirects to while using GM_xmlhttpRequest

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey, window.location, gm-xmlhttprequest

Imagine you are on a website called "www.yourWebsite.com", and you're using userscripts in Tampermonkey to get information from another website. In this case, you are using the GM_xmlhttpRequest function.

When you're using the GM_xmlhttpRequest function to go to "exampleWebsite.com", sometimes it redirects to "exampleWebsite.com/partOne", and sometimes it redirects to "exampleWebsite.com/partTwo".

Your goal is to find out whether it redirected to "exampleWebsite.com/partOne" or "exampleWebsite.com/partTwo". Now I've been trying to use window.location.href to find out where it redirected to, but all I've been getting is the website I'm on, which is "www.yourWebsite.com".

How I do fix this?

```
     var GoToURL = "exampleWebsite.com"; 
     GM_xmlhttpRequest({
     method: "GET",
     url: GoToURL,
     onload: function(response) {

     alert(window.location.href);

     } //end of onload: function(response) {
     }); //end of GM_xmlhttpRequest({
```

Comment: Try the following :"window.location.pathname" which will get paraments after the domain

Comment: @HarishKarthick That will not work. The `window.location` will not have changed from just a `GM_xmlhttpRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

In Tampermonkey, at least, you can check the `finalUrl` property of the response to identify where the redirect leads to. For example, with a PHP page of

```
<?php
header('Location: https://www.google.com/');
?>
```

then the following userscript will result in `https://www.google.com/` being logged to the console:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: GoToURL,
  onload: function(response) {
    console.log(response.finalUrl);
  }
});
```

Comment: This nominally also works with *Violentmonkey* and it worked with Greasemonkey prior to the colossal mess that is Greasemonkey 4.